# Captioning tcolorbox

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, tcolorbox

Inside my latex document I have several `tcolorbox`-es and several `tcblisting`-s and they are just fine. However, I would like to add a caption on every of them and mark then so they will be visible in the listings at the end of book, just like for example, `\listoffigures` and `listoftables`. Is this achievable and if it is, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and quite straight forward using the `list inside` option to `\newtcolorbox`.

Say, a box type `MyBox` is to be created, which should be counted and a list of those boxes should appear. Define a list type, say, `mybox` and use `list inside=mybox` as init option to `\newtcolorbox`.

The list uses `\jobname.mybox` then to store the entries.

Using `\tcblistof[\section*]{mybox}{Some title}` the generated list can be displayed as it would have been created with `\listoffigures` etc.

The entries to the box can be set using `title=`, or `list entry=` as option to the box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newtcolorbox[list inside=mybox,auto counter,number within=section]{MyBox}{colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=black,title={MyBox \thetcbcounter}}



\begin{document}

\tcblistof[\section*]{mybox}{List of MyBox}

\section{First}
\begin{MyBox}
\blindtext
\end{MyBox}

\begin{MyBox}
\blindtext[3]
\end{MyBox}

\section{Other}

\begin{MyBox}
\blindtext[4]
\end{MyBox}



\end{document}
```

The manual of `tcolorbox` (version 3.90) has a full example in section 14.10 for use with listings/TeX exercises.

[image]