# framed with counter and list of frames

Tags: frame-title

I'd like make a box that looks a little bit like this. With a meter (chapter number dot box number) here (1.2) because there will be many. And then for a list of all the box with the command (`\listoframe`). Do you have any idea?

Thanks !!

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: My \documentclass{book}

Comment: I've done something similar recently with `tcolorbox` package: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234015/captioning-tcolorbox

Comment: Can the close voters read the questions properly before voting for duplicate?

Comment: I agree with percusse. SoundsOfSilence did a good thing by linking a related question, but it doesn't make a duplicate. If this gets closed, I'll vote to reopen. @user60268 Will you ever have a need for multiple tabs?

Comment: I did not mean that the question is a duplicate, rather related, my answer there being a starting point

Answer (score 3):

With `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter,list inside=mybox]{mybox}[2][]{%
boxrule=1pt,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
colbacktitle=red!85!black,enhanced jigsaw,
attach boxed title to top left=
{xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm},
boxed title style={enhanced, size=small,boxrule=0pt,arc=0pt, colback=blue!20,colframe=red,toprule=1pt,leftrule=1pt,rightrule=1pt},
title=Frame~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

\makeatletter % no indent for entries
\renewcommand{\l@tcolorbox}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
% temporarily make \numberline do nothing
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{mybox}{List of my boxes}
\endgroup

\chapter{First chapter}
  \begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{Hello there}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{mybox}

  \begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]{}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]